No cache header whatever
I have a webcam that uploads a image every 15 min to a folder on my webserver.
And then i have a wordpress page that display this image.
The problem is the browser caches the image and it will not update when i refresh the page after 15 min.
I have tryed different options like function wp_get_nocache_headers(), img.decoding = "async";, and some META no-cashe stuff, but nothing works.
There is a 99% chance im doing it wrong!
Can anyone giv my a step, by step guide how to prevent browser cache on my webcam image?
And only the one page with the image.

You have to give us something to work with, a bit of code. What does the code for your page currently look like? Do you want to see the newest image automatically? How would we retrieve it?

The simplest way to is just add some cache-busting into the URL of the image. For instance you might be able to add the file's modification date/time in the query string. Alternatively, you could just append a random string to the URL in the QS, too, although that might have some perf issues depending on your site's traffic.

Have you tried setting a cache-control: no-cache response header in the webserver settings? You can likely make it send that specifically for that URL. I doubt doing anything in PHP would work - if the URL points directly to an image file then PHP isn't involved in serving it, but your webserver is.

Let's suppose you have a path to the image, such as
my/path/to/the/image.jpg

and when the browser loads this, then it caches it, that is, it saves it locally so the image is not requested for again until the cache lifecycle passes. And of course you have no control over the cache of your users' browser.
But, if you have something like this instead:
my/path/to/the/image.jpg?v=123

then whoever loaded this image without the v parameter being 123 will have his/her browser actually retrieving the image. So, you can associate a timestamp to the upload of your image and append it as a parameter, like
t=<the timestamp>

where "the timestamp" is of course a number and you change that number whenever you override the image, so you allow the browser of your users to cache the image, but at the next upload, the timestamp being different from the one that was previously used will actually force the browser of your user to retrieve the image and not to rely on the cache when the image is to be overriden.

Thanks for answering. But do you have an exact example i can use? Im not a coder, so i need the exact code and exactly where to put it :-)

@RobinAndersen I do not have an example in front of me, but I applied this idea like 10 times. If you need more exact ideas, more code-like statements, that's good. But then I kindly ask you to edit your question and show your code where your image is being displayed along with some context, like the code around it, filename, etc.

Hi! I have posted an aswer below with the things i have tryed and the URL to the site. Maybe that helps? Thanks

@RobinAndersen thank you. But this is more like an edit to your question than an answer, you can click on the edit button of your question and add the additional information into your question. Also, you said you tried image.jpg?nocache=<?php echo time(); ?> and it did not work. Can you tell me how it did not work? Can you show more of the code around it? What happened? Was a cached image shown to you?

This is the html: <img decoding="async" src="https://visitbudor.no/webcam/webcam2/Skitrekk.jpg?nocache=" "="" alt=""> And this serves only a cached image. If i refresh my browser i get the same "old" image. If i clear browser cache, i get a new and updated image. But i might be missing something her? Is there some other code i also should implement somewhere?

@RobinAndersen if you right-click on your image in the browser what do you see as its src?

The src is: src="visitbudor.no/webcam/webcam2/Skitrekk.jpg?nocache=" "="" alt="">

@RobinAndersen that src could look good if it was parsed by PHP. But it isn't parsed by PHP. Instead it is written into your HTML as raw HTML value. In your page source you should end up having something like src="visitbudor.no/webcam/webcam2/Skitrekk.jpg?nocache=368483". Also, you might want to check the strange "="" just after your src value as well.

Thanks for pointing me in the right directions. I finaly got it to work.

@RobinAndersen happy to help. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.
